# Override material in linked object 2.82

Tags: materials

I have an object with many materials that I want to link and use a lot of copies of.

But I want to override one material so that in copy A the material is X and in copy B the material is Y.

How do I achieve that best in 2.8?

I read that the new way is overrides instead of proxies and I'm a bit confused.

EDIT:

I achieved to override the material ONCE. But now all the instances have the same material (which I have overridden) but still I dont want them to have the same material...

This is what I have now:

[image]

Comment: Any links re material overrides? (Please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/178350/edit) into question)

Comment: Im a bit a noob in blender, what do you mean with that?

Comment: Re _"I read that the new way is overrides instead of proxies"_

Comment: Ah right that was here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/files/linked_libraries/library_overrides.html